# Bash script not working, doesn't change directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

First off, I only just started learning how to use Linux yesterday so my abilities are very limited.

I am essentially creating a script that I can run everytime I turn on my VPS and the script then turns on all the servers. However due to my lack of knowledge I have ran into some difficulties as once the script gets to turning the servers on it doesn't change the directories, leaving it as the default directory.

I am not sure if I am doing it right at all, so if you find a mistake in the script it would be great if you could correct me - or if you have a more efficient way of doing something.

```
#!/bin/bash
service mysqld start
sudo service httpd restart
sudo service vsftpd restart
echo finished initialization
cd ~/server_1 & dos2unix start.sh & sh start.sh & 
cd ~/server_2 & dos2unix start.sh & sh start.sh & 
cd ~/bungee_1 & dos2unix start.sh & sh start.sh && 
fg
echo finished
```

Comment: What will happen if you do `cd ~/server_1 &`?

Comment: It will fork it and run it in the background in a different shell ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to use `&&` instead of `&` ?

Comment: No I believe one & makes it run as a background process?

Comment: It will run it in the background and not wait for it. How can you guarantee that it is still in the same directory to run the `dos2unix` and then the `start.sh` ?

NB: my question was more of a statement.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry I changed some of them from & to && and I think that solved it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Josh the `set -e` command would be another way to check (everything) for errors and abort the script on any failure.